# Css cache issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I got a  problem with my css cache,I got a page which loads transcations of that particular user.I used jquery table sorter to sort the table which inplace creates a arrow icons on the end of .It works fine for most of the time but some times the arrows doesnt show up.i need to do a manual CSS clear cache ctrl+r or cntrl+F5 to get the icons back.Is there any alternative to clear the css cache on succesfull page load.so that we do not need to manually refresh the page to get the icons.It happens both on IE and mozilla.

Comment: Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Comment: Is this for your own development or a production problem? (Do you want it to work better for you or for the visitors to your page?) Instead of clearing the cache you might implement a system which appends a number to the filename whenever a change has been made. For example adding a querystring parameter might help for the latter. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\mycssfile.css?version=1" />`

Comment: this was for an application which i work on,i am trying for better approaches many suggest for a new plugin.But close to prod,dnt want to mess up the code adding a new plugin.so finding out for better code fix.Seems like ur solution gonna work out for me.But,on my scenario i am not making any changes on the page.A defalut rendering of my page should come with the expected jquery sorting tabel.Instead of going for a manual refresh.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just started using [this](http://david.dojotoolkit.org/recss.html) bookmarklet to refresh CSS while I was working on a page that responded wonky to page reloads. If you take that logic, you can call it on page load and it should update your style sheets.